# recvfrom doesn't give the correct sender address when used in a thread

Tags: multithreading, sockets, udp

I am learning basic socket programming in C++. I noticed that when the `recvfrom()` function is called from a separate thread, the sender address is not received correctly.

Here is my `server.cpp` file, with only the main thread:

```cpp
void receive(int sockfd) {

  char buffer[1024];
  int n;
  socklen_t len;

  struct sockaddr_in cliaddr;
  memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr));

  n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, 1024,
              MSG_WAITALL, ( struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr,
              &len);
  buffer[n] = '\0';
  printf("Received from client : %s\n", buffer);
  printf("s_addr : %d, sin_port: %d\n", cliaddr.sin_addr.s_addr, cliaddr.sin_port);

}

// Driver code
int main() {
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    // Filling server information
    servaddr.sin_family    = AF_INET; // IPv4
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = 16777343;
    servaddr.sin_port = 63786;

    // Bind the socket with the server address
    if ( bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,
            sizeof(servaddr)) < 0 )
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    receive(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

The produced output is:

```
Received from client : Hello from client
s_addr : 16777343, sin_port: 37261
```

But, when the function is executed from a different thread:

```cpp
std::thread t(receive, sockfd);
t.join();
```

The output becomes:

```
Received from client : Hello from client
s_addr : 0, sin_port: 0
```

Meaning that the sender address is not received properly.

Any idea? Note that when I try to create and bind the socket from inside the thread, the result is the same.

Comment: You are not validating the return value of `recvfrom()` for errors before using `n` as a buffer index. `recvfrom()` returns `-1` on failure.  For instance, `errno` may be reporting `EFAULT` or `EINVAL` in your situation, but you would be ignoring that.

Answer (score 3):

```
ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *restrict buf, size_t len, int flags,
                    struct sockaddr *restrict src_addr,
                    socklen_t *restrict addrlen);
```

> Before the call, addrlen should be initialized to the size of the buffer associated with src_addr.

So, you need to fix this by the following way:

```
socklen_t len = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
```